# how can I upload backup of SQLite db to the google drive, and restore it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-drive-api

I am new to using Google Drive API, I tried some samples but it didn't work well
like this:

https://github.com/stevenchang0529/XamarinGoogleDriveRest

It works fine, but when I try to sign in, **I get this error**:

> Error 400: "redirect_uri_mismatch"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Error 400: "redirect_uri_mismatch"` means  the callback url in the setup of the OAuth of Google end is incorrect.

In that sample project, there are two keys in the MainViewModel:

```
  private string clientId = "put your client Id from goole api console";
  private string redirectUrl = "xamarin.test.driverest:/oauth2redirect";
```

You need to [console.cloud.google](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/drive.googleapis.com?q=search&referrer=search) to get the correct redirectUrl.

There are also steps in the read.me of the Github project:

```
1.On Google API Console,Add Google Drive API
2.Add OAuth2.0 Credential for Android.
3.change client id in MainViewModel.cs.
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jack,I found Redirect URL, and I put it instead of "xamarin.test.driverest: / oauth2redirect"
It worked fine, but it opens the account selection page in
Web Authentication Native Browser and asks to enter the account password, how can I have it open the account selection Popup directly